# For probability density function

Tags: probability, functions

I would like to know what this is:

$P(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the symbol for real numbers.

I have seen this before but just cannot recall what it meant.

Comment: Could mean basically *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $P(.) : \mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$, that's shorthand for "define $P$ to be a function that can take any real number as input and gives a real number as output". If your function took a pair of real numbers as input and output a complex number, you'd write $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ instead, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A $\textbf{probability density function}$ (in your setting) is a real-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ($f$ is nonnegative),
2. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$ (the area under the curve $f$ is $1$).

If $X$ is a continuous random variable, we define $P(a\leq X\leq b) := \int_a^b f(x)dx$.

The notation $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers, i.e., it contains all rational and irrational numbers.